# How to construct dataset in memory that is built from CSV and VRT file?

Tags: gdal, vrt, gdalbuildvrt, gdal.net

I'm using GDAL .Net wrapper, [GDAL.Net](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp).

I have a list of scattered points ( in `X,Y,Z` coordinates) that I would like to rasterized via the function [`GDAL_GRID`](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html)( or via the underlying .Net wrapper, `Gdal.wrapper_GDALGrid()`. Currently this is what I do:

1. I write the list of scattered points to CSV file
2. Then I construct the `.vrt` file that maps to the previous CSV file, by using relevant .Net XML libraries.
3. And then I use the `GDAL.Dataset ds =Gdal.OpenEx(vrtFile, 0, null, null, null))` in .Net to read the contents of vrt file and CSV file into `Gdal.Dataset`, so that I can use the `Gdal.wrapper_GDALGrid(tiffFile, ds, null, null, string.Empty)` to create the raster file `tiffFile`.

Note that step 1 and 2 touch the file system, which I'm thinking of doing away with.

Is there anyway that I can create the `GDAL.Dataset ds` straight from the scattered points, all in memory, without writing the scattered points to CSV, and create vrt file on disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built on Marc Pfister's [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/306864/1261), I can come up with a GDAL.Net version that works well, despite that the correct binding for `Layers` in `GDAL.Dataset` is missing.

Here's the code:

```
    private Dataset CreateDataset(List<Tuple<double,double,double>> csvData, string tempDir)
    {
        var driverOgr = Ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile");
        var dsOgr= driverOgr.CreateDataSource(tempDir, null);
      var layerOgr =  dsOgr.CreateLayer("polyPoint", null, wkbGeometryType.wkbPoint25D, null);
        var fieldDef = new FieldDefn("location", 0);
        layerOgr.CreateField(fieldDef, 0);

        for(int i=0; i< csvData.Count; i++)
        {
            using (var feature = new Feature(new FeatureDefn($"point {i}")))
            {
                var geometry = new Geometry(wkbGeometryType.wkbPoint25D);
                geometry.SetPoint(0, csvData[i].Item1, csvData[i].Item2, csvData[i].Item3);
                feature.SetGeometry(geometry);
                layerOgr.CreateFeature(feature);

            }
        }

        //need to use this to work around the missing layer in Dataset binding, https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/918
        var dsGDAL = new Dataset(DataSource.getCPtr(dsOgr).Handle, false, null);
        return dsGDAL;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to follow a similar pattern to the ["Writing to OGR"](https://www.gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html) tutorial:

- Create a new GDAL.Dataset object
- Add a feature layer to store points
- Use your geometry list to create Point objects
- Add them to the feature layer
- feed the Dataset object to GDAL Grid

Comment: Have you tried doing the above? I believe the above approach will work if you want to burn the point list direct into the `Dataset`, but I'm unsure if it works if you need to have `vrt` to refer to the point list

Comment: You don't need a VRT - `Grid(destName, srcDS, **kwargs)`:  `Args: destName --- Output dataset name, srcDS --- a Dataset object or a filename`

Comment: Also it should be noted that currently the correct binding for `Layers` in `GDAl.Dataset` for GDAl.Net [is missing](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/918).

Comment: Bummer, that kills that strategy.

Comment: You have any more ideas on this?

Comment: The only other idea would be to use a memory mapped file but I would be surprised if that worked.

Comment: I've come up with a workaround, see [my answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/307014/1261)